# Single/double dispatch via "dynamic overload" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parametric-polymorphism

Why double dispatch via "dynamic overload" based on argument type isn't natively supported by C#? I see this would require dynamic dispatching but since virtual method calls are also dispatched dynamically this would not be that strange to the language. So why this feature is not part of C#? What would be most elegant solution to implement this functionality using Reflection (maybe there are some libraries)?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objs = new object[] { new Class1(), new Class2() };
        foreach (var item in objs)
        {
            Method(item);
        }
    }

    static void Method(Class1 obj)
    {
    }

    static void Method(Class2 obj)
    {
    }
}

class Class1
{
}

class Class2
{
}
```

**UPDATE** indeed, because `Method` in this example isn't virtual and takes only one argument this would be still single dispatch but "cardinality" of dispatch isn't that important in this question as long as it's > 0.

Comment: At least some form of parametric polymorphism is available in C#/C++ and Java via templates/generics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`virtual` is for single dispatch. If you need double dispatch, you could do this in C#:

```
var objs = new object[] { new Class1(), new Class2() };
foreach (var item in objs)
{
    Method((dynamic)item);
}
```

This will make the compiler interpret the call to your method in a very different way. It will emit a so-called *call site* which will determine at runtime which method should be called. This is also called *late binding*.

In this specific example you still get single dispatch, but it would have been double dispatch if `Method` were virtual.

This is very convenient to quickly implement the visitor pattern, but be aware that this will be slower than classic manual double-dispatch. So you may want to use the good old way in performance-sensitive code.

Comment: @Matías In this example it is technically *still* single dispatch. But it would have been double dispatch if `Method` were virtual.

Comment: I think the correct term is parametric polymorphism

Comment: Right, added parametric-polymorphism tag to the question.

Answer (score 4):

> Why double dispatch via "dynamic overload" based on argument type isn't natively supported by C#?

It is, via [dynamic typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objs = new object[] { new Class1(), new Class2() };
    // Note the change of type for item to "dynamic"
    foreach (dynamic item in objs)
    {
        Method(item);
    }
}
```

Operations involving a value with a compile-time type of `dynamic` are late-bound - so overload resolution is performed at execution-time, based on the *actual* type of the value. There's a lot more to dynamic typing than just overload resolution, of course, including types being able to provide members dynamically via code.

There's a performance hit for all of this - but *sometimes* it's the cleanest approach.

You may want to add an extra overload with a parameter of type `object` as a "catch-all" in case a value doesn't match either of the other overloads... although it would still be ambiguous if your array contains a null element.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this approach. Do you mean `Method` will be called twice, one for `Method(Class1)` and also `Method(Class2)`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Yes, that's right. It will pick the overload to call based on the execution-time type of the value.

Comment: Well, I understand that. I misunderstood double dispathing with calling `Method` ONCE... and resolve both overloads. Nevermind, I got crazy :D

Answer (score 3):

If you are really interested, Andrew Kennedy , One of the designers of the .Net CLR generics, wrote an article about this.

http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64039/transposingftocsharp.pdf

Since F# which has true parametrized polymorphism uses the same Common Language Runtime, presumably C# could also have implemented it, and the decision was one of preserving the C++/C# language style.

From his article : "Similarly, the CLR implementation of polymorphic virtual methods [10] involves execution-time code generation, contrasting with the load-time code generation that is sufficient to support non-virtual polymorphic methods."